# CollapsingToolbarLayout pushes toolbar text outside the screen.

Tags: android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Hi I'm trying to use Collapsing Toolbar but when the collapsing toolbar collapses the title of the toolbar moves outside the screen. I'm using right alignment for the text as i'm trying to build an app in Urdu language. I have searched on this and not no solution. Need help!
[See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9uZB.png)
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mrvirk.urduapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/quran"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:title="@string/Quran"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quranTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/Quran"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"

                    />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="12dp">



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quranIntro"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="9"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/intro"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quranDesc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/description"


                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/fav"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a better answer or solution to this problem. Now i have added a TextView at the right of the toolbar title. Which basically consume some space so the title comes at the required place. And i know its not the best practice. If someone has a better solution Please share.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/toolbar"
                app:title="@string/Quran"
                android:gravity="right"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your **CollapsingToolbarLayout** try to add this      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" 
like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: As you can see i have added layout_scrollFlags and you are trying to duplicate this line of code. This does not help me out